# Run javascript with value of field onload

Tags: javascript

Trying to have script run on page load with value of input on page load.  The script runs onchange fine but I also want to run on page load.  I have tried    onload="calculateAmount(this.value);">

```
<input type="number" name="tot_pin_requested" id="tot_pin_requested" class="inputbox autowidth" value="{{ PPDEFAULT_VALUE }}"   onchange="calculateAmount(this.value);">

 <script>
            function calculateAmount(val) {
                var price = val * 1;
                //display the result
                var tot_price = price + (price * 0.029 + .30);
                tot_price.toFixed(2);
                var divobj = document.getElementById('amount');
                divobj.value = tot_price;
            }


        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add it to the element, just have it separate:

```
<script>calculateAmount(document.querySelector("#tot_pin_requested").value);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure the document is ready just use `DOMContentLoaded`  event.

Also i suggest you use `parseFloat` on the inputValue so it's correctly changed from type string to type number. ( or parseInt(value, radix) if you will have just int values )

Also i don't know what is the logic behind `var price = val * 1`....

See below

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById('tot_pin_requested').value

  calculateAmount(parseFloat(inputValue))
})



function calculateAmount(val) {
  var price = val * 1;
  //display the result
  var tot_price = price + (price * 0.029 + .30);
  tot_price.toFixed(2);
  var divobj = document.getElementById('amount');

  divobj.value = tot_price;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="tot_pin_requested" id="tot_pin_requested" class="inputbox autowidth" value="10" onchange="calculateAmount(this.value);">
<input type="number" id="amount">
```